# R - Converting a string variable with "\t" and "\n" into a data frame

Tags: r

I have a varible containing string:

`"A\tB\n\C\tD"`

How can I convert it into a data frame like this?

```
---------
| A | B |
---------
| C | D |
---------
```

I have used this workaround: first write it as .txt file and then read as .tsv file.

```
writeLines("A\tB\n\C\tD", "A.txt")
B <- read.table("A.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

I am pretty sure that there is a more effective way to convert one to another without creating a new file, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about using `read.table()`.

- Use `read.table(text=your_string, sep="\t")`, emphasis on the `text` parameter.
- The `text` parameter allows you to input a string instead of a filename.

Also, in your variable string, you have `"A\tB\n\C\tD"` where there is a `\` before the `C`, I don't know if that's an error or not but if you take that `\` out, the input should be fine (like `"A\tB\nC\tD"`)

Comment: My bad, extra \ is a misprint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text=` argument:

```
s <- "A\tB\nC\tD"
read.table(text = s, as.is = TRUE)
##   V1 V2
## 1  A  B
## 2  C  D
```